# Bash shell script update and print a variable overwriting the same line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, output

I been trying to print a variable in the same time for a scrip that pretends automatize a process the content is the output of this

```
sed "s/Read/\n/g" /tmp/Air/test.txt | tail -1 test.txt | grep ARP
```

so i put this in a while loop

```
    do
       out= sed "s/Read/\n/g" /tmp/Air/test.txt | tail -1 test.txt | grep ARP
       echo  -n  "$out"
       sleep 1
    done
```

i read other questions here and i try with different option like `echo -ne`, `echo -ne "$out" \r`, `printf "\r"` or `printf "%s"` and no luck with no one, all the other example don't have a variable to print just counter o system variables

Update

it seems to appear that the `echo -n` repeat `$out` in the same line, if `out="this is a test"` the output of `echo -n` is "this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test ...." maybe im missing some option ?

Update 2

sorry for the miss understood perhaps i was not very clear but what i want is overwrite the same line with the value of $out, the source of $out is the output of the aireplay-ng command that executes along with the script and i get the output with

the ouput is something like this

```
102415 packets (got 5 ARP requests and 15438 ACKs), sent 37085 packets...(499 pps)
```

but the number of ARP request is changing constantly

this code for example use echo -ne and overwrite in the same line

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for pc in $(seq 1 100); do
       echo -ne "$pc%\033[0K\r"
       sleep 1
    done
```

the output of this is like a percent indicator that shows "10%" and going instead of "1% 2% 3% 4% 5% .." in the same line and i already try like this but with no luck

Comment: didnt get your question correctly but im assuming you can try to do `out=$(sed ...)` or just do `echo $(sed ...)`, you can remove the `echo` as well since `grep` would print it anyway

Comment: can you post your whole script and input files so that we can find out whats the exact problem?

Comment: is a simple function and basically that is the whole code, the output is from the aireplay-ng command and is something like this

        102415 packets (got 5 ARP requests and 15438 ACKs), sent 37085 packets...(499 pps)

i ran some test with a comon text file and the same commands and it seems to appear that the echo -n option is working but is adding the result in the same line

if the content of the text file is "this is a test" the echo -n shows "this is a test this is a test this is a test ... "

Comment: Eh? "this is a test this is a test this is a test" is exactly what one would **expect** it to print if you were doing it right (in a loop): It's printing the same content over and over without a newline inbetween. Isn't that what you're asking for?

Comment: BTW, if there are potentially other control characters in your string, consider `%q` instead of `%s` to print them in a human-readable, unambiguous form rather than emitting them to the terminal as they are and letting the terminal interpret them.

Comment: ...is the goal here to update a status line? That wasn't clear: "Update and print a variable in same line" could just be read to mean that you wanted to use only one line of code for both operations.

Comment: apologize for the miss understood perhaps i not be clear but what i wan is update the status in the same line, the souerce of $out is the dump of the aireplay-ng command that is executing along with the scrip so the value of $out it would be differente along the output of the aireplay-ng command so what i want is update and overwrite the same line with the value of $out

Comment: and yes if you see the example code that i left behind using echo -ne in a for loop the script overwrite the same line until the output is 100% and not mi goal is not use just one line of code for two operations is just update $out overwriting the same line so the user can see the progress of the command without get his screen full of the normal command output, thank a lot for the help

Comment: Gotcha. What's given in my answer, below the bar, should address that. If it doesn't, *something else* is printing a newline -- potentially built into your value for `$out`, potentially being printed through a different file descriptor such as stderr.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are assigning a value of bash command wrongly to variable.

```
out=$(sed "s/Read/\n/g" /tmp/Air/test.txt | tail -1 test.txt | grep ARP)
```

Then you can print all your output in one line as you wrote:-

```
echo -n $out
```

Comment: Can't have a space after the `=` in assignments.

Comment: Yeah !!! Thanks for correction.... Edited

Comment: dint work, i try as you say and no luck with that, always print $out in a new line in every loop instead of print again in the same line

Comment: aside: `echo -n` isn't guaranteed by POSIX to leave off a trailing newline (or do any other particular thing; the POSIX spec for `echo` simply leaves it undefined). `printf '%s' "$out"` is more robust.

Comment: i all ready tried with printf '%s' "$out" but i have no luck with that maybe i was not very clear but i want to overwrite the same line instead of continue adding the $out value in the same line, thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to execute the sed Please use

```
`sed "s/Read/\n/g" /tmp/Air/test.txt | tail -1 test.txt | grep ARP`
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction i changed it but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The recent addendum to your question reads like you're miscommunicating your intent: `this is a test this is a test this is a test` is what a plain reading of your question indicates you to be *asking for* (printing `this is a test` over and over in a loop without newlines, after all, can be expected to do nothing else); why you'd describe this in a context that makes it sound like a bug is thus surprising.

---

If you want to send the cursor back to the beginning of your current line and overwrite that line, that might be something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ not /bin/sh; this enables bash extensions

# ask the shell to keep $COLUMNS up-to-date
shopt -s checkwinsize

# defaults to 80-character terminal width, but uses $COLUMNS if available
printf "%-${COLUMNS:-80}s\r" "$out"`
```

...which prints your string, pads out to 80 characters with spaces, and then returns the cursor to the beginning of the line, such that the next thing you write will overwrite that string.

Of course, if you print that line and then return to a shell prompt, the prompt will start at the beginning of the same line and overwrite the text, so be sure to follow up with an `echo`.